# Why aren't my session variables being passed to the other pages?

Tags: php, oop, session, authentication

I have a class Authenticator that uses Datatype User to log in users.

```
include('User.datatype.php');

$usher = new Authenticator;
$usher->checkCreds();
$usher->startSession();

Class Authenticator {
    protected $user;
    protected function getCreds() {
        if (!isset($_POST['login']))
                throw new Exception("There was an error processing your request", 1);
        else if ($_POST['username'] == '' || $_POST['password'] == '')
            throw new Exception("You must enter a username and password", 1);
        $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $this->user = new User;
        $this->user->username = $username;
        $this->user->password = $password;
    }

    public function checkCreds() {
        $this->getCreds();
        if (empty($this->user->username) || empty($this->user->password))
            throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);
        include('dbconnect.php');       // Normally I'd store the db connect script outside of webroot
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_password);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = :uname AND password = :pword');
        $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $this->user->username);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pword', $this->user->password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $status = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $this->user->status = $status;
    }

    protected function createSessionID() {
        $seshID = mt_rand(99999, 1000000000);
        return $seshID;
    }

    public function startSession() {
        if ($this->user->status === false)
            throw new Exception("There was a problem connecting to the database", 1);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $this->user->username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $this->createSessionID();
        $secret = $_SESSION['id'];
        header('Location:loggedin.php?' . $secret);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The login works and session_starts() works, but when I try 
`print 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['username'];` on loggedin.php, the session variable is empty.

HTML for loggedin.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Product Cost Calculator</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <?php
                    /*require_once ('Authenticator.php');
                    if (!Authenticator::startSession())
                        print 'you are not logged in';*/
                    print 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['username'];
                ?>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you have to start_session **first**

Comment: I'm sorry, where? The HTML or in the PHP function?

Comment: in each php call, POST or GET, through ajax, regular browser request or SUBMIT action, the session has to start on the top of the php file.-

Comment: I don't want the session to start until I know the correct login information was used.

Comment: but there are 2 different things: the php session and the applicative session layer of your application. The latter needs the former to work, but should be independant

Comment: I added it to the top of Authenticator.php and in loggedin.php. I am receiving the warning Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: authenticator.php is not necessary, only in the interfaces files, meaning the files receiving the POST or GET request. Authenticator.php is *included*, this is different, it has the session already started.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Now, where do I put my header() statement so that it goes after session_start()? It's sitting inside of the class method right now

Comment: I think it is fine, because you don't send any response to the initiator of the GET or POST request before you call `header()` If you don't get the headers already sent error this is fine. But you should extract it outside of the class: the function should return true or false, and then according to that you should redirect or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a session in the current page to make use of session related code

```
session_start();
include('User.datatype.php');
//rest of code etc etc
```

Comment: Oh, I see, it won't override anything?

Comment: `session_start()` does not override the session, it does **intialize** it. `session_destroy()` - as the name suggests - destroys the whole session.

Comment: When I added it, I got the following warning: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: That problem occurs if you send some data (to the browser) via `echo`, `print` or just outside of PHP tags before calling `sessoin_start()`.